# elastic constants transformation/basis change P21/a -> P21/n

Tags: solid-state-physics, mechanical-properties, elastic-constants, atomistic-simulation, elasticity

I just calculated the stiffness tensor for a given material (a monoclinic molecular crystal)
using molecular simulation. When trying to compare my results to published experimental results
I found that the crystal structure I used for simulation, though essentially the same as the one
used as reference system in experiment, has different base vectors/reference frame
(P21/n vs P21/a) - therefore I can compare invariants and averages but not the individual
components c_ij of the stiffness (as matrix in Voigt notation).

So my question is: given the, altogether six, lattice vectors of the two crystal structures,
how can I use this information to generate a rotation matrix to transform
the Voigt matrix from experiment (based on a crystal in the P21/a space group) so that
I can compare it to my calculated numbers from simulation (based on a crystal with P21/n
symmetry)?

What comes closest to an answer I found here:
http://solidmechanics.org/text/Chapter3_2/Chapter3_2.htm
but I am not sure what the two bases (e and m, in section 3.2.11 Basis change formulas
for anisotropic elastic constants) are - are these the normalized lattice vectors of the
two structures in Cartesian coordinates? if not what else?

thanks!

michael

Answer (score 4):

In order to define the matrix transforming the P21/n structure into P21/a it is imperative to know the unique axis of both space groups.

For example the contracted P21/n symbol can be used for the full P21/n11 symbol (unique monoclinic axis along a), for the full P121/n1 (unique axis along b) and for the full P1121/n (unique axis along c).

The same apply for P21/a (i.e. it could stand for P21/n11,...).

So you have to understand the exact settings of space groups, then you can find the transformation matrix relating them. For example, if you have the initial and final settings P121/n1 -> P121/a1 (same unique b axis in bth space groups), the corresponding transformation matrix is:
[-1 0 1]
[ 0 1 0]
[-1 0 0]
that is -a-c,b,a

If you have P121/n1 -> P1121/a, than the transformation matrix is -a-c,c,b

Comment: thanks for your answer! ... I am not sure though whether it answers the question ... I am looking for a rotation matrix to convert the stiffness tensor (either the 4th rank tensor, or preferably the Voigt matrix), and not just to rotate the structure/coordinates - or are these the same?

Comment: sorry and one more follow up ... I want to convert C21/a to C21/n (and not the other direction as discussed by you) - would I just use the inverse of the matrix you provided in this case?

Comment: what do you mean with C21/a and C21/n? It seems to me that these space groups do not exist.

Comment: In any case to answer to your first comment, I never made a transformation with a 4th rank tensor, but it shuold be the same as for a 2nd one.

Comment: sorry ... i meant P21/n or a .... typo ... and I was talknig about a voigt matrix which is not a tensor at all, but it can still be transformed with a nother matrix to account for a differnt base/reference ... so what i meant can i use the rotation matrix you provided for this purpose?

Comment: I suggest to take a look at some textbook, this would be much easier (the description is quite complicated); now I'm not in my office to suggest some of them, but I guess that in every book on crystallophysics it is described how to do.

Comment: In any case you have to define what is the monoclinic unique axis because " P21/n or a" is not yet clear. From your last comment I don't understand if you want to transform the compoments of your tensor (as I understood in your question) or redefine the structure with the new setting or something else.

Comment: I think that you can find how to do in one of these textbooks: 1) J. F. Nye, Physical Properties of Crystals
2) Wooster, Crystal Physics
3) Newnham, Physical Properties Of Crystals

Comment: thanks ... i've had a look at all three, unfortunately there's no straight forward answer in any of them ... but obviously the basic background is there, so i have to figure it out myself somehow ... this appears to be surprisingly non-trivial ;) even if the two crystal symmetries are fully defined, which they are as i have all lattice vectors for the two cases ... for now i;m doing it by visual inspection, followed by guessing the rotation axis and angles, and then use the matrices from the link i gave in the original post ...

Comment: for a 4-rank tensor indeed the situation is more complicated, but the basis of the transformations are describd in Cap 1 and 2 of the book of Wooster. for a 3-raank tensor look at Cap 5 of thee same book.